# Gumbel distribution: consistency check for MLE

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, maximum-likelihood

> Consider $X$ a Gumbel distributed random variable with pdf $$f(x)=\exp(-(x-\mu)-\exp( \mu-x) ).$$ Find the MLE for the parameter $\mu$ based on $n$ i.i.d. observations from a Gumbel population. Show that this estimator is consistent.

**My attempt:**

I already found that $\hat{\mu}=\ln(n)-\ln\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \exp(-X_i) \right)$. To check for consistency, I'd have to find the distribution of $\hat{\mu}$ and prove $P(|\hat{\mu}-\mu|>\epsilon)\to 0$ for $n\to +\infty$. The expression for $\hat{\mu}$ makes me think that this is probably not the way to tackle this problem.

How can I find the distribution? Should I approach it differently? A question in general: what are some useful methods to *explicitly* show consistency of MLE?

Thanks.

Comment: For checking consistency, no need to find exact distribution (unless it is obvious). In some cases, asymptotic distribution or the first two moments for large $n$ may come in handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually (in the so-called regular settings) the consistency of MLEs is proved by using the strong or the weak law of large numbers, i.e., 
\begin{align}
\hat{\mu}_n &= \ln n - \ln\left( \sum e^{-X_i} ) \right)\\
&=\ln n - \ln\left(n  \frac{1}{n}\sum e^{-X_i} ) \right)\\
&=\ln n - \ln n - \ln \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum e^{-X_i}  \right)\\
&=- \ln \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum e^{-X_i} ) \right),
\end{align}
by the WLLN
$$
\hat{\mu}_n \xrightarrow{p} - \ln ( \mathbb{E}[e^{-X}]) = -\ln (\Gamma[2]e^{-\mu})=\mu.
$$
For the last part see here 
[2-sided Laplace transform of $\exp(-(t + e^{-t}))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1606962/2-sided-laplace-transform-of-exp-t-e-t)